# Print from High to Low occurrences of Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that counts every word in a file and counts how many times they occurred.

```
filename = "test.txt"

output = []

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]

wordlist = {}

for line in content:
    for entry in line.split():
        word = entry.replace('.', '')
        word = word.replace(',', '')
        word = word.replace('!', '')
        word = word.replace('?', '')

        if word not in wordlist:
            wordlist[word] = 1
        else:
            wordlist[word] = wordlist[word] + 1

print(wordlist)
```

However, when I print this, I am not able to specify to go from high to low occurrences.

Here is a test file.

```
hello my friend. hello sir.
```

How do I print such that it looks like
`hello: 2 (newline)`
`my: 1`
etc?

Comment: so the problem is with print? i can see you ocurrences are being counted properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import string
filepath = Path('test.txt')
# print(filepath.exists())
with open(filepath) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

word_list = sum((
    (s.strip('\n').translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))).split(' ')
    for s in content
), [])

for key,value in Counter(word_list).items():
    print(f'{key} : {value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `python3.7` and up the `dict` preserve the insertion order. So we can just sort the dictionary item by values and then insert(or create) in new `dict`.

Use:

```
print(dict(sorted(wordlist.items(), key = lambda x: -x[1])))
```